# How to solve problems in pom.xml maven in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I imported a project in eclipse with maven but I got some errors in the `pom.xml` file which I report here:

```
`Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'PhoneBook'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6`
```

I installed Eclipse EE so that Maven is integrated. Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: Do you have a proper internet connection without a proxy in between?

Comment: make sure you have internet connection, and paste here your pom.xml and maven's settings.xml (usually under MAVEN_HOME/config)

Comment: I have an internet connection. I checked and I figured out that I have no settings.xml in maven folder. But oh my gosh! I tried to force the "maven update" from eclipse for the project and now seems to work.